# Windows batch file to crop images in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a lot of images in a folder. I want to crop all the images at specific coordinates and save the converted folder to sub-folder with the name of the file suffixed with crop. I am using ImageMagick command line option convert to crop single file with the help of below given command:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick" convert -crop 60x40+525+240 "C:\temp\rose.png" "C:\temp\temp\rose-crop.png"
```

I want to do the same process for every file present in that folder and the converted file should follow the same naming convention. I tried this:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick" convert -crop 60x40+525+240 %%i %%i
```

But it is overriding the existing images. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Why aren't you specifying the output folder?

Comment: Well, you specified the same file as source and destination, so the described behaviour is not really a big surprise; specify source and destination directories also in the `for` loop (remove `/R`, by the way), and - if you like - append something to the destination names: `for %%I in ("D:\source\*.*") do "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick" convert -crop 60x40+525+240 "%%~i" "D:\target\%%~nI-crop%%~xI"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process a whole folder of images using the magick mogrify command in ImageMagick 7. Create a new empty folder for the output (or backup your input). Cd to the directory with your images, then

```
magick mogrify -path path_to/new_folder -format png -crop 60x40+525+240 +repage *.png
```

That will crop every png image in your current directory and place the cropped results in the new_folder directory. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Supply your path for my placeholder path_to. Change to using Windows paths with \ rather than my unix syntax of /